# Error in DropDownList using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, datareader, system.data

I have a DropDownList called (DDL) in ASP.net page, I want that DDL contains some records of a table in the data base.

So I did this :

```
DDL.DataSource = myDataReader

DDL.DataBind()
```

But it's giving me (5 records) "the number of records of the table" but like this :

```
System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternel
System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternel
System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternel
System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternel
System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternel
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set DataTextField and DataValueField, otherwise data binding will perform .ToString() on every row and put it as item:

```
DDL.DataSource = myDataReader;
DDL.DataTextField = "[Text column name]";
DDL.DataValueField = "[Value column name]";
DDL.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the text and the key fields of the ddl before you databind

```
DDL.DataTextField = "textColumn";
DDL.DataValueField = "textColumn":
```

Answer (score 0):

The code : `ddl.datasource=reader` is just setting the content present in reader (array of columns of table) as the main source of data.
Now as `ddl` show only a single column in it so u need to write a piece of code which tells `ddl` that which column it has to display.
So you will write:  `ddl.textfield=`"column name which you want to show";
and      `ddl.valuefield="`column name which you want as a reference to pass to database";

Comment: Just FYI, you're answering a year-old question, and your answer duplicates the accepted answer. :)